# Node js Json checking if a specific key and value exists and then getting its value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

the following JSON is returned to me from the API

```
[
  {
    type: 'atom',
    id: 'atom',
    atom: { type: 'priceWithTitle', priceWithTitle: [Object] }
  },
  {
    type: 'atom',
    id: 'atom',
    atom: { type: 'price', price: [Object] }
  },
  {
    type: 'atom',
    id: 'name',
    atom: { type: 'textAtom', textAtom: [Object] }
  },
  { atom: { type: 'labelList', labelList: [Object] } }
]
```

Briefly how do I get this data:

```
......

const JsonFromApi = JSON.parse(DataFromApi)
console.log(JsonFromApi)

// After that I get Json from above
```

To refer to a specific group of elements, I need to specify it.
For example, in order to get the block I need (which contains the price, it is the second in a row), I need to specify [1], for example

```
console.log(JsonFromApi[1]) // After that I get the element I need, below will be the json i get:
```

```
{
  type: 'atom',
  id: 'atom',
  atom: {
    type: 'price',
    price: {
      price: '532 $',
      priceColor: 'amTextSecondary',
      originalPriceColor: 'amTextSecondary',
      theme: 'STYLE_TYPE_MEDIUM',
      strikethroughColor: 'amAccentAlert'
    }
  }
}
```

> **So what's the problem?**
>
> The JSON that is returned to me from the API can change the order of
> the elements inside, for example, now I applied for the price of a
> product using [1], another time or with another product, the element
> will be [2], [3] or another.

> **Question - :**
> How to get the data I need if the order of the elements
> is constantly changing, the only clue is -> atom: { type: 'price',
> price: [Object] }
>
> type: contains type information about the type of data inside, How do
> I first check which element contains the type I need and then get its
> value, for example -> get the price of the goods?

Comment: Loop through your data with a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or something like [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and when you find an object that has `obj.atom.type === "price"`, then you've found the object you're after. Related: [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150)

Comment: .find() returns - .find() is not a function.

Comment: `find()` is absolutely an instance method on Arrays in JavaScript; are you sure you’re calling it on your array correctly…? If so, what user agent are you testing this in that doesn’t have support for this construct?

Comment: Nick Parsons, esqew - Thanks for support, answer already found. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function hasOwnProperty() on the atom object

```
const object = [
  {
    type: "atom",
    id: "atom",
    atom: { type: "priceWithTitle", priceWithTitle: [Object] },
  },
  {
    type: "atom",
    id: "atom",
    atom: { type: "price", price: [Object] },
  },
  {
    type: "atom",
    id: "name",
    atom: { type: "textAtom", textAtom: [Object] },
  },
  { atom: { type: "labelList", labelList: [Object] } },
];

function checkPrice(object) {
  object.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.atom.hasOwnProperty("price")) {
      console.log(element.atom.price);
    }
  });
}
```